# submit value of radio button with jquery with onClick event

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, form-submit

I have a simple toggle button on a page which uses two radio inputs:

```
Foo: 
<input type='radio' name='foo' value='bar'> Bar <br>
<input type='radio' name='foo' value='fru'> Fru
```

Is there a short and easy way (preferably with JQuery) of asynchronously submitting the value of `foo` each time it is clicked?

The radio buttons above are the only form elements on the page.

Comment: Have you tried looking into `$().change()` and `.ajax` or `.post` more specifically, using them together?

Comment: submitting the value where?

Comment: @Dagon - to a script (such as foobar.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this maybe?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("input:radio").change(function(){
         $.post('ajaxScriptLocation.php', { "foo": $(this).val() }, function(data) {
           // do whatever with data result.
         });
      });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Does `.click` work for radio buttons? I always thought it was `.change`

Comment: $.post failed because permissions were wrong on the receiving script.  Once that was fixed, the snipped above worked as expected.